# how to find subnet mask of a server linux

Tags: mask, subnet, nslookup

I have the linux server.
i dont have rights to connect to the linux sever ; but i know the hostname ; ip address ;
is it possible to know the sub nets mask ? any commands like nslookup or other commands exists ?
Advance thanks

Comment: Without at least an address of any of the subnets, it's a bit hard to find it. It would be ifconfig but you must connect to the server (which is excluded in this case). Do you may know any IP connected to that server?

Comment: hello ; thanks for the information ; i will try to find if any ip connected to the server.
 thanks once again